# Magento 2: change price section in sales email template

Tags: magento2, price, email

i tried to remove a price section from orders emails.
For example for new order email e receive a FPT price which I want to be removed
[image]

For this, I found that this price came from  `magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml` :

```
 <td class="item-price">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
 </td>
```

`getItemPrice` function looks like this:

```
  public function getItemPrice($item)
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('item_price');
        $block->setItem($item);
        return $block->toHtml();
    }
```

What i tried to do now is to find which block is '`item_price`' to know the phtml related with this block, because i think there  is the place where my price is rendered, but i can't find.

The only thing I found was `sales_email_tem_price.xml` which have the name "item price' with `email/items/price/row.phtml` related tot this, but after i made some changes in this file nothinghappened,and i think  that this is not the file.

Does anyone how the price in email is renedered and how can i remove my FTP section from email?

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours debug i found that the price in email order is rendered in

> /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/price/row.phtml